# Triggering python logger in Django project

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a Django project that has the following function in which I want to trigger a logger:

```
def remove_email_from_list(list_id, email_address):
    subscriber_hash = hashlib.md5(email_clean)
    url = '%s/lists/%s/members/%s' % (settings.API_URL, list_id, subscriber_hash.hexdigest())
    r = requests.delete(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', settings.API_KEY),)
    if r.status_code != 204:
        logging.critical("Executed mailchimp api call, wrong status code. Message body = " + r.text)
    return r
```

However, I tried all these loggers to catch this error and send an email, but somehow the logger isn't triggered. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True
    },
    'project_name.logging': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.logging': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you call `logging.critical` directly, this is done via the default logger.
Create a named logger first by using (somewhere in the head of your py-file):

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and then call

```
logger.critical(...)
```

This should then use the logger with the package name of the file you are in

See [Logger Objects Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects)

Comment: Hmm I am still having some trouble to configure this. This file (helper_functions.py) is located in the root of my application "mail". If I would define my logger as "api_logger", I should have to use the logger with "mail.api_logger"? That still doesn't catch my logs.

Comment: No, no not replace '__name__' by anything custom. '__name__' is automatically replaced with the modules dotted path. If you replace '__name__' by 'api_logger' you would probably have to use the same name in the logger config.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude and use a double 'no'. I actually meant to write 'No, do not', Also the double underscores were removed by the formating, sorry for that. should have been `__name__`